# What does the phrase 'cross-cutting initiatives' mean?

Tags: meaning, phrases, expressions, comprehension

> “The bold but feasible **cross-cutting initiatives** in this report will improve outcomes for patients with cancer, prevent cancer and increase our understanding of cancer,” said Dr. Lowy.

Here is the link to where the phrase came from, in case any one wishes to get a wider context. The sentence was mentioned in line number 13.
http://www.cancer.gov/news-events/press-releases/2016/ncab-nci-accept-brp-report

Answer (score 2):

> **cross-cutting**   *adjective*
>
> linking traditionally separate or independent parties or interests:
>
> *a multi-agency, cross-cutting approach on drugs.*
>
> — [Collins English Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/cross-cutting) –

So the original passage means something like :

*The bold but feasible initiatives in this report **will require the involvement of several health-service groups**.
They will improve outcomes for [...]*

Comment: I read this as being similar to the concept of 'breaking down silos' which is a common way of talking about encouraging greater and more effective cooperation between departments within an organisation. I would expect a 'cross-cutting initiative' to operate not only across different health-care groups but also to promote greater cooperation between workers in different areas and disciplines of research.

Answer (score 1):

Cross-Cutting in medicine, recently, is aiming to apply basic science as is. Looking for understanding the treatment benefits while some theoretical or empirical experiences were driven from basic sciences.

Comment: Thanks for answering.  Can you add some links to references or sources so that readers can do more research on their own?